# How to catch database exception and not display it to browser?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to catch exception from query error or other database error in codeigniter 2.1.3 and display it or hide in another template, not in the browser actually.

I have done like this before :

```
//Setting in config/database.php
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE; 

//then in the view
echo $this->db->_error_message(); 
echo $this->db->_error_number();
```

But nothing change, I have set my apllication in database error condition before, to test that I can catch the error or not.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if codeigniter has a special way of doing this but in regular php code you could just use a normal try catch block.

```
try {
    // get data from database
    // use data
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an exception if there's any problem like this:

```
 try {
      //data from database

 } catch (\Exception $e) {
     throw new \Exception('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
 }
```